# C# Update UI from async task in a different class

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a modified asynchronous socket listener running based on Microsoft's example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

So it's always running and listening for incoming data.

I'm running it from the winform like this:

```
Task.Run(() => { AsynchronousSocketListener asl = new AsynchronousSocketListener(); });
```

I have a label on my form called LastMessage, once some data has been received on the socket I want to:
1. Make it visible
2. Change the text of the label to a value I extracted from incoming data from the socket listener.

I've searched around and tried to implement multiple solutions but couldn't get it working and I feel like I'm missing or misunderstanding something, what code needs to run on the form, what needs to run in the task, and most importantly, the server always has to stay up to listen for more incoming data, since all the solutions I saw are waiting for the task to end or return some value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html

Comment: "*but couldn't get it working*" so where is the code you're actually working on? please update your topic but keep it minimal